# PhoneGap/Cordova: Windows Phone: Blue border of links

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone

I have small problem with GUI. All images which have tags `<a>...</a>` have blue border. See example on attached screenshot.

[Example with blue borders of links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXz8k.png)

Can I resolve my problem using CSS or I must delete all links `<a>...</a>` and use JS functions instead of these tags for processing of taps.

Comment: try (a {outline : none;})

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: `a img{ border: none; }` -- this code works fine!

Comment: This is an HTML/CSS issue. This has nothing to do with any of the tags you used. I recommend you learn HTML. I've been doing this for over 20 years and I learned this in the first month. By book, read tutorials, etc.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, it's related to only  tag `<a>` and only to webview of windows phone (specific of IE). Same issue is reproducible if you open any site in old IE (IE8 for example).

Comment: My point is that the **Stackoverflow tags** you are using are incorrect. Your question and where you posted it points to a lack of experience, which is apparent. Best of Luck.